Magento 2.4.7-p1 Checkout Blank
Have a strange issue.
Upgraded to 2.4.7-p1 and the checkout is now blank. /checkout I have disabled all the modules just keeping the default modues there, changed the theme to the Magento Blank. Its running PHP 8.3.9. Has anyone came across this before and managed a fix?
I have disabled all the modules just keeping the default modues there, changed the theme to the Magento Blank.
Done the CSP Parts too

In your custom module, create a config.xml file under etc folder, paste the provided code into that file, and then run the following command:
php bin/magento cache:flush
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront_checkout_index_index>
                    <report_only>1</report_only>
                </storefront_checkout_index_index>
            </mode>
            <policies>
                <storefront_checkout_index_index>
                    <scripts>
                        <inline>1</inline>
                    </scripts>
                </storefront_checkout_index_index>
            </policies>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>

